# Defining new syntax in Emacs

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting

I have a custom config file format and I would like Emacs to recognize and highlight the syntax.  Is this possible.  If yes, how do we do it?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a [link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_syntax_coloring.html) I used a whileback to create my own c# mode (before a more complete one was created):

Goes through step by step what to do.

Out of curiosity, which file format are you going to write?

As you might know, modes can be quite powerful, for example [nxml mode](http://www.thaiopensource.com/nxml-mode/) actually validates XML schemas for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm writing a config file format with which we can store 3 levels of data.  Actually I'm just experimenting with the format structure also.  Felt syntax highlighting would help.